# Asp.Net Mvc jQuery Datatable RowOrder Drag&Drop and Id problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, jquery-plugins

I have been working on a survey application with Asp.Net MVC. I have 2 adjent tables on the page where I assign a question to the survey. What's important to me is the table on the right. This table can be added from the question pool on the left. It should also be possible to change the order of rows in the table on the right. But in this table, I encountered a problem while dragging and dropping a row. I'm dragging the line, but it doesn't stop where I left it back to its original place.

the rowReorder.dataSrc property should be used, as described in [this thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53573/is-rowreorder-currently-not-working#Comment_144296). But when the datasrc property is given the question id of its own data, the lines change when you drag and drop, but the id part always remains in order. Of course, it's ridiculous that id lines are placed in ascending order while the lines of the questions are changing. The 'Question' object and data are as follows.

**Question.cs object**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>


namespace MerinosSurvey.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Questions
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Questions()
    {
        this.Responses = new HashSet<Responses>();
        this.Options = new HashSet<Options>();
        this.SurveyQuestions = new HashSet<SurveyQuestions>();
    }

    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }     
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedUserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }


    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Options> Options { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<SurveyQuestions> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Json Data**

```
{
"data": [
{
  "Responses": [

  ],
  "Options": [

  ],
  "SurveyQuestions": [

  ],
  "QuestionId": 1,
  "QuestionName": "Merinos ürünlerinden ne kadar memnunsunuz?",
  "QuestionTypeId": 1,
  "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1577048400000)\/",
  "CreatedUserId": 1,
  "IsActive": true,
  "Status": true,
  "UpdatedDate": "\/Date(1577663808297)\/"
},
{
  "Responses": [

  ],
  "Options": [

  ],
  "SurveyQuestions": [

  ],
  "QuestionId": 2,
  "QuestionName": "Merinosun satis magazalarindan memnun musunuz?",
  "QuestionTypeId": 1,
  "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1577048400000)\/",
  "CreatedUserId": 1,
  "IsActive": true,
  "Status": true,
  "UpdatedDate": "\/Date(1577048400000)\/"
},
{
  "Responses": [

  ],
  "Options": [

  ],
  "SurveyQuestions": [

  ],
  "QuestionId": 3,
  "QuestionName": "Merinosun müsteri temsilcilerinden memnun musunuz?",
  "QuestionTypeId": 1,
  "CreatedDate": "\/Date(1577048400000)\/",
  "CreatedUserId": 1,
  "IsActive": true,
  "Status": true,
  "UpdatedDate": "\/Date(1577048400000)\/"
}
]
```

}

**Jquery Datatable ajax call**

```
$("#rightTable").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Survey/GetRelatedQuestions",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": { "surveyId": surveyId },
            "datatype": "int"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            { width: '10%', targets: 0 }
        ],
        //"scrollX": true,
        //"scrollY": "auto",
        "columns": [
            {"data": "QuestionId"},
            {"data": "QuestionName"}
        ],
        //responsive: true,
        ordering: false,
        info:true,
        rowReorder: {
            dataSrc: 'QuestionId',
            selector: 'tr'
        },
        "language": {
            "emptyTable":
                "Ankete ilişkilenmiş soru bulunamadı. "
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you

Jquery datatable have rowReordering and createdRow event.just use that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  'ajax': {
     'url': '' 
     },
  'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex){
     $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
  }    
 });
    table.rowReordering();   
  });
```

Comment: thanks for response. But I am getting an error like Uncaught TypeError: rightTable.rowReordering is not a function

Comment: To use rowReordering() you need to initialize your table as $('#rightTable').dataTable(), not $('#rightTable').DataTable().

Comment: For detail information                                                                                            Refer this URl                                                                                     https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/

Comment: I know I already initialized my datatable as; var rightTable = $("#rightTable").DataTable({. 'creatdRow':.......}) then I added rightTable.rowreordering();

Comment: There is an note in the page you send; 'There is a row reordering plug-in for jQuery DataTables that allows drag and drop row reordering in the table. Sadly this plug-in no longer works with DataTables 1.10 and above.' My Datatable version is 1.10.20

Comment: ok..Refer this URL I hope this will fix your issue https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/examples/initialisation/events.html

Comment: I don't want to add new field to my db model object.This is nonsence  I think